# Refresh "root" data inside a UINavigationController and update data in navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using storyboard with a UINavigationController that has view controllers A, B and C.

A is the root view controller of the navigation controller which at startup fetches some data. If I click on a row in A that will segue to B view controller with that data. Clicking on a row in B will segue to C view controller.

Later in my app for instance I'm inside C and the user wants to refresh the data. Meaning I need to fetch the root data for A view controller again.

How do I rebuild my navigation hierarchy again after the user have refreshed the data? I need to update the data source in A and then in B and then finally in C somehow.

Comment: Can you not simply refresh the data that's being displayed in C? Or do you really have to refresh the entire root?

Comment: Well all data should be updated otherwise it would be in an inconsistent state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's merely a matter of planning ahead, isn't it? It's *your* program so it's *your* job to provide *yourself* with the facilities that *you* will need. In this situation there is no need to "rebuild" anything (though you could do that, I suppose). A and B both do still exist even while you're showing C, so all you have to do is communicate with them as needed. If the data-fetching power resides only in A, then simply provide A with a method that C can call in order to request the refresh and receive the updated data. If A and B are subsequently *shown* again (because the user pops back from C), they will of course use their `viewWillAppear` to update their respective *interfaces* as well. But at the moment A and B are merely *objects*, and communicating between objects is, after all, what object-oriented programming is all about.

Comment: Well A "houses" the fetched data. B is showing a subset of A's data and C is showing a subset of B's data. I'm thinking that after I have done the fetch again I need to update the data property in A, B and C? Meaning I need to get a reference to the navigation controller and access it's view controller property to get access to the navigation stack and update the data is the view controllers right?

Comment: That is certainly one way, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40986685/341994 But there are other ways, perhaps better. For example, you could pass along a reference to A, from A to B and then from B to C. Or, going even further, you could pass along a reference _to the data_ from A to B and then from B to C, perhaps wrapped in a helper object that has the knowledge of how to do the refresh. That is how _I_ would do it. Apple calls this pattern "dependency injection": provide each successive view controller with all that it will need.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the logic of A in another objet which could be accessible from A and C. 
I think this [post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1) is a good place to start